# iOS 7 - Possible bug in CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

In my app I need to know user location and then load an array from a DB. So I created an instance of CLLocationManager

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *gps;
```

In viewDidLoad I set some properties of gps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.gps = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.gps.delegate = self;
    self.gps.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}
```

and in viewDidAppear I start to update user location if my table view is empty:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] <= 0) {
        [self.gps startUpdatingLocation];
    }

}
```

Now when gps find user location, it calls the delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"DID UPDATE LOCATIONS");
    [self.gps stopUpdatingLocation];
    if (!didUpdateLocation) {
        didUpdateLocation = YES;
        currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadDistance) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [self caricaLocaliInOrdineAlfabetico:NO];
    }
}
```

The problem is in the delegate method cause SOMETIMES (not always) it is called more than one time even if I ask gps to stopUpdatingLocation. As you can see I also tried to declare a BOOL called didUpdateLocation to check if user location was already taken, but it seems to be useless. How is possible?

Here is the debug log:

```
2014-05-05 18:22:02.324 AppName[9529:60b] <FMDatabase: 0x16d5e740> executeQuery: SELECT * FROM locali
2014-05-05 18:22:02.483 AppName[9529:60b] DID UPDATE LOCATIONS
2014-05-05 18:22:06.002 AppName[9529:60b] CARICA LOCALI
2014-05-05 18:22:06.005 AppName[9529:60b] LOCALE INDEX: 170
2014-05-05 18:22:06.009 AppName[9529:60b] <FMDatabase: 0x16e6b040> executeQuery: SELECT * FROM locali ORDER BY distanza ASC
2014-05-05 18:22:06.068 AppName[9529:60b] DID UPDATE LOCATIONS
2014-05-05 18:22:09.784 AppName[9529:60b] CARICA LOCALI
2014-05-05 18:22:09.791 AppName[9529:60b] LOCALE INDEX: 170
2014-05-05 18:22:09.802 AppName[9529:60b] <FMDatabase: 0x16e72130> executeQuery: SELECT * FROM locali ORDER BY distanza ASC
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you should specify the storage type of our @property (make it (nonatomic, strong) generally) and access it as self.gps rather than just gps. In the first code section you're just declaring the variable, and you create the actual object in the second section. Very different concepts.

Comment: You have right @wjl, but even if I change it with self.gps I have the same problem..

Comment: While Martin is right, that you should anticipate (and program for) the possibility that there might be additional location updates that might slip in, there is, an aside, a logical disconnect between your asking for `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` with no `distanceFilter`, but only grabbing the first one that comes in. If you really don't care about the `horizontalAccuracy`, you might want to set `desiredAccuracy` to something like `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`. Likewise, you might set `distanceFilter` to something other than the default `kCLDistanceFilterNone`.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is flawed.

The location manage gives very bad results when you first ask for location updates, and takes a while to settle down and start giving good results.

You can't take one and only one location reading and assume it's an accurate location. Most often it will be very inaccurate.

You need to check the time stamp on your location updates, and reject updates that are more than a few seconds old. This is because the location manager caches the location it read when the GPS was last running, and will sometimes give you a first location reading that is hours or days out-of-date, and can be wildly wrong.

Next, you'll start getting readings with very poor horizontal accuracy. The first couple of readings can be off by a kilometer or more. You need to be taking updates until you get one that is accurate enough for your purposes. (The accuracy reading is actually a radius value that indicates how much possible error there could be in the reading.)

You need to code your location updates to throw away inaccurate readings, and also eventually time out if you don't  get a satisfactory reading in a reasonable amount of time (30 seconds would be a good starting point.)

Only when you get a reading that has a recent timestamp and has a low enough accuracy reading should you process the reading. At that point, set your "didUpdateLocation" flag and stop location updates.

Comment: With an iPhone at least, it usually innately has a broad sense of where it is because it knows which cell tower it is attached to. So you should get that very quickly. Subsequently it'll need to do a quick Wifi scan and REST stuff and/or locate four GPS satellites to give either of the more accurate measures, and its final and most accurate answer will be a combination of all of that.

Comment: @Tommy, my description of CLLocationManager behavior is based on testing on actual iPhones.

Comment: I'm sure it was and that this is the correct answer, that's why I didn't posit one of my own; I was trying to provide background colour for the questioner to explain why the behaviour you accurately report occurs, i.e. that there are several mechanisms for getting location, that higher accuracy ones have greater time costs and that the best accuracy isn't obtained until all are combined.

Comment: You have right @DuncanC, the first informations about current location are quitely inaccurate. What do you think about stop updating location when a good average accuracy is taken? Something like `float averageAccuracy = (currentLocation.verticalAccuracy + currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy) / 2 if (averageAccuracy <= 40) didUpdateLocation = YES`

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bug.

didUpdateLocations: can continue to be called for a short while after stopUpdatingLocation has been called so you should code for this.

Comment: I think the same, that's why I created a BOOL to check if location is already taken, but the method (and the if cycle) is called anyway. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the use of the bool in that snippet, unless you are inadvertently setting it elsewhere also.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to avoid the problem is by using a timer. Now, even when the delegate method is called more than one time, there are no problems.

In .h file

```
NSTimer *loadDistanceTimer;
```

In .m file

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    float averageAccuracy = (currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy + currentLocation.verticalAccuracy) / 2;
    NSLog(@"DID UPDATE LOCATIONS WITH %.0f AV_ACC",averageAccuracy);
    if (averageAccuracy < 20) {
        [self.gps stopUpdatingLocation];

        if (loadDistanceTimer == nil) {
            loadDistanceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                                 target:self
                                                               selector:@selector(loadDistance)
                                                               userInfo:nil
                                                                repeats:NO];
        }
    }
}

- (void)loadDistance
{
    // while cycle here
    while (something) {
        //do something
    }

    loadDistanceTimer = nil;
    [self caricaLocaliInOrdineAlfabetico:NO];
}
```

As DuncanC said, the first location taken from gps may be inaccurate, so I calculate an average accuracy from horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy to improve the accuracy of current location.